# How to capture only TCP traffic with tshark

Tags: network-protocols, tshark

I have the following command:

```
tshark -n -r ./file.dump -Y "(tcp.flags.syn==1 or tcp.flags.ack==1 and tcp.flags.fin==0)"
```

For some reason prints and ICMP messages.

How can tell tshark to print only tcp packets?

The only that I'm thinking is to grep it `grep "TCP"`. But it not a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For some reason prints ICMP messages.

Wireshark/TShark dissect the payload of ICMP messages; if they happen to include part of a TCP segment, that will be dissected, so the packet will contain those flags).

> How can tell tshark to print only tcp packets?

```
tshark -n -r ./file.dump -Y "not icmp and (tcp.flags.syn==1 or tcp.flags.ack==1 and tcp.flags.fin==0)"
```